# C# - Ausência de argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro formal necessário em código de classes abstratas

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes-abstratas

Há um **erro de argumentos fornecidos em 3 construtores** de meu código de classes abstratas, onde o método **obterSalarioBruto()** devem ser escritos nas classes filhas da **classe Funcionário** que são as classes **FuncionarioMensalista** e **FuncionarioHorista**.

---

### Imagem para melhor visualização e entendimento do diagrama do código

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Os seguintes construtores do meu código a serem analisados são:

- **1 Construtor na Classe Funcionário (Linha 10, afeta linha 62)**.
- **1 Construtor na Classe FuncionarioMensalista (Linha 25, afeta linha 63)**.
- **1 Construtor na Classe FuncionárioHorista (Linha 44, afeta linha 64)**.

---

Atual código

```
using static System.Console;

public class Funcionario
{
    public int numeroRegistro { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Complemento { get; set; }

    // 1º construtor
    public Funcionario (int numeroRegistro)
    {
        this.numeroRegistro = numeroRegistro;
    }

    // Deve retornar o valor de zero
    public virtual decimal obterSalarioBruto() => 0;

    public string Imprimir1() => $"Número de registro: {numeroRegistro} | Nome: {nome}";
}

public class FuncionarioMensalista : Funcionario
{
    public decimal valorSalarioMinimo { get; set; }
    public decimal quantSalarioMinimo { get; set; }

    // 2º construtor
    public FuncionarioMensalista(int numeroRegistro) : base(numeroRegistro)
    {

    }

    // valor do salario mínimo multiplicado pela quantidade de salários mínimos.
    public virtual decimal obterSalarioBruto()
    {
        decimal resultado1 = (valorSalarioMinimo * quantSalarioMinimo) + base.Complemento;
        return resultado1;
    }

    public string Imprimir2() => $"Salário mínimo: {valorSalarioMinimo.ToString("C")} | Quantidade de salário mínimo: {quantSalarioMinimo.ToString("C")}";
}

public class FuncionarioHorista : Funcionario
{
    public decimal valorHora { get; set; }
    public decimal horasTrabalhadas { get; set; }

    // 3º construtor
    public FuncionarioHorista(int numeroRegistro) : base(numeroRegistro)
    {

    }

    //  valor da hora trabalhada multiplicado pela quantidade de horas
    public virtual decimal obterSalarioBruto()
    {
        decimal resultado2 = (valorHora * horasTrabalhadas) + base.Complemento;
        return resultado2;
    }

    public string Imprimir3() => $"Valor das horas: {valorHora.ToString("C")} | Horas trabalhadas: {horasTrabalhadas.ToString("C")}";
}

public class Imprimir
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario(); // Linha afetada
        FuncionarioMensalista mensalista = new FuncionarioMensalista(); // Linha afetada
        FuncionarioHorista horista = new FuncionarioHorista(); // Linha afetada

        Write("Digite o nome do funcionário: ");
        funcionario.nome = ReadLine();
        Write($"Digite o valor do registro de {funcionario.nome}: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out int digiteregistro)) return 1;
        funcionario.numeroRegistro = digiteregistro;
        WriteLine();

        Write("Digite o valor do salário mínimo: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digitesalario)) return 1;
        mensalista.valorSalarioMinimo = digitesalario;
        Write("Digite a quantidade de salários mínimos: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digitequantidade)) return 1;
        mensalista.quantSalarioMinimo = digitequantidade;
        WriteLine();

        Write("Digite o valor da hora: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digitehora)) return 1;
        horista.valorHora = digitehora;
        Write("Digite a quantidade de horas trabalhadas: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digitehorastrabalhadas)) return 1;
        horista.horasTrabalhadas = digitehorastrabalhadas;
        WriteLine();

        WriteLine(funcionario.Imprimir1());
        WriteLine(mensalista.Imprimir2());
        WriteLine(horista.Imprimir3());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Em: "Há um erro de argumentos fornecidos em 3 construtores de meu código de classes abstratas" Suas classes Funcionario, FuncionarioHorista e FuncionarioMensalista não são abstratas.

2) Nas linhas afetadas onde cria as instâncias de Funcionario, FuncionarioHorista e FuncionarioMensalista você não está passando o argumento necessário para o construtor.

Answer (score -1):

```
public abstract class Funcionario
{
    public int numeroRegistro { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Complemento { get; set; }

    // 1º construtor
    public Funcionario (int numeroRegistro)
    {
        this.numeroRegistro = numeroRegistro;
    }

    // Deve retornar o valor de zero
    public virtual decimal obterSalarioBruto() => 0;

    public string Imprimir1() => $"Número de registro: {numeroRegistro} | Nome: {nome}";
}
```

Teste isso e deve solucionar, você deve decorar a classe com a palavra reservada "abstract".

Answer (score -1):

Na classe `Funcionario`, você tem o método virtual, ou seja, pode ser sobrescrito por classes que herdem ela..

Nas classes `FuncionarioHorista` e `FuncionarioHorista` você quer sobrepor método da base, então você deve indicar usando `override`

A sua classe `FuncionarioHorista` deve ficar assim:

```
public class FuncionarioHorista : Funcionario
{
    public decimal valorHora { get; set; }
    public decimal horasTrabalhadas { get; set; }

    // 3º construtor
    public FuncionarioHorista(int numeroRegistro) : base(numeroRegistro)
    {

    }

    //  valor da hora trabalhada multiplicado pela quantidade de horas
    public override decimal obterSalarioBruto()
    {
        decimal resultado2 = (valorHora * horasTrabalhadas) + base.Complemento;
        return resultado2;
    }

    public string Imprimir3() => $"Valor das horas: {valorHora.ToString("C")} | Horas trabalhadas: {horasTrabalhadas.ToString("C")}";
}
```

Comment: Alguém me explica por que do -1?